# Remember me in WordPress without checking remember me

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to extend expiration users without check remember me in the WordPress login form or any WordPress plugins?
Users should able to sign in for a month even they closed their browsers!
I used `auth_cookie_expiration`, but it doesn't seem to work for remember me, it just extends the expiration and when I closed the browser I couldn't be able to access my account.

Comment: Your best bet is probably pre-checking the field - it's important to have in case someone's logging in on a shared computer or something. There are plugins for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remember-me-controls/

Comment: Tangentially: please re-consider this design to "force" users into longer session expirations without their consent. In my view (and I'm sure many others') it's a crucial part of UX to provide an option to those using shared/public computers to ensure their sessions are destroyed even when they might not explicitly log out from the application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the filter is actually executed it can be included in a plugin file or in a `functions.php` of your current active theme.

You can extend the expiration as:

```
add_filter ( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'extend_login_session' );
 
function extend_login_session( $expire ) {
    return YEAR_IN_SECONDS;
}
```

You can replace `YEAR_IN_SECONDS` with any of the following constants available in WordPress.

- `MONTH_IN_SECONDS`
- `DAY_IN_SECONDS`
- `HOUR_IN_SECONDS`

Or you can just return any number the number is the number of seconds for the expiration of the cookie.